# .cmd files are not getting executed except "startweblogic.cmd" in Weblogic, for the rest the command window is getting closed immediately

Tags: cmd, weblogic12c, java-home

I have set environment variable for `JAVA_HOME` and SQL driver `.jar` file.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151;
```

and

```
C:\Users\appuser\Downloads\InforSoftwares\sqljdbc41.jar
```

Comment: Try to run it as cmd /k *.cmd, this way you will see the output before the window closes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the issue was with the Java environment variable. I had set it correctly. Now the files are getting executing.